# Resampling data with the 'mean' method

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample 15 minute data to 60 minute data by using the pandas .resample function with the 'mean' method, but by default this method takes the average of the 9:00 AM, 9:15 AM, 9:30 AM, and 9:45 AM  values for the 9:00 AM timestamp (as an example). Is there a way to instead take the average of the 8:15 AM, 8:30 AM, 8:45 AM and 9:00 AM values for the 9:00 AM timestamp?

Input data:

```
Generated On                CB_P
2019-01-01 08:15:00+00:00   0.187
2019-01-01 08:30:00+00:00   0.228
2019-01-01 08:45:00+00:00   0.242
2019-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   0.8270
2019-01-01 09:15:00+00:00   1.083
2019-01-01 09:30:00+00:00   3.022
2019-01-01 09:45:00+00:00   1.511
2019-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   1.568
2019-01-01 10:15:00+00:00   6.365
2019-01-01 10:30:00+00:00   8.23
2019-01-01 10:45:00+00:00   9.3
2019-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   14.311
2019-01-01 11:15:00+00:00   13.045
2019-01-01 11:30:00+00:00   11.05
2019-01-01 11:45:00+00:00   11.257
2019-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   13.367
2019-01-01 12:15:00+00:00   11.895
2019-01-01 12:30:00+00:00   9.245
2019-01-01 12:45:00+00:00   7.254
2019-01-01 13:00:00+00:00   15.773
2019-01-01 13:15:00+00:00   14.280
2019-01-01 13:30:00+00:00   17.258
2019-01-01 13:45:00+00:00   7.792
2019-01-01 14:00:00+00:00   6.893
2019-01-01 14:15:00+00:00   4.693
2019-01-01 14:30:00+00:00   4.271
2019-01-01 14:45:00+00:00   1.524
2019-01-01 15:00:00+00:00   1.495
2019-01-01 15:15:00+00:00   1.03
2019-01-01 15:30:00+00:00   0.364
2019-01-01 15:45:00+00:00   0.045
```

Expected output:

```
Generated On                CB_P
2019-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   0.371
2019-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   1.796
2019-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   9.5515
2019-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   12.180
2019-01-01 13:00:00+00:00   11.04
2019-01-01 14:00:00+00:00   11.556
2019-01-01 15:00:00+00:00   2.996
```

Comment: The `mean` method of *what*?

Comment: My bad, I edited the post.

Comment: Is this your expected output data?  Do you have input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offset values can be used for resampling. Kindly refer to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

```
df['Generated On'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Generated On'])
df.set_index('Generated On', inplace=True)
df2 = df.resample('1H', offset=15).mean()
df2.index = df2.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df2  
                    CB_P
Generated On    
2019-01-01 08:00:00 0.371000
2019-01-01 09:00:00 1.796000
2019-01-01 10:00:00 9.551500
2019-01-01 11:00:00 12.179750
2019-01-01 12:00:00 11.041750
2019-01-01 13:00:00 11.555750
2019-01-01 14:00:00 2.995750
2019-01-01 15:00:00 0.479667
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It gave me the desired output but is there a way to then remove the offset from the index, because the resulting dataframe doesn't work with the rest of my code now.